# Cloudflare Lost 2FA and can't login

Tags: cloudflare

How can I retrieve my Cloudflare account if I have lost my 2FA app (MS auth one)
I can't get access cause I have taken the factory reset on my phone

Answer (score 1):

Please email supportATcloudflareDOTcom from your account email, we'll respond back with potential options for recovering your account and verifying ownership.

If this isn't possible in your case, an alternative is to create a new Cloudflare account and sign the domain up, you can then verify ownership of the zone by changing your nameservers to a different pair. Note that you will lose all your existing configuration if you choose this option.